# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - decrement value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, increment, decrement, on-duplicate-key

The following seems odds to me:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (UNIQUEVALUE,NUMERICVALUE) VALUES ('valuethatexists','100') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE NUMERICVALUE = NUMERICVALUE+VALUES(NUMERICVALUE);
```

Assume your `NUMERICVALUE` is at 0.

The above would change it to 100 - which does work.

If, however, you then input -100, it does not work properly.

```
INSERT INTO sometable (UNIQUEVALUE,NUMERICVALUE) VALUES ('valuethatexists','-100') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE NUMERICVALUE = NUMERICVALUE+VALUES(NUMERICVALUE);
```

The above statement should return it to 0. It does not, in my case. It remains at 100.

Am I missing something?

Edit: This goes wrong somewhere else. I am doing this with PHP. The actual code exhibiting this bug looks like this:

Edit 2: This had nothing to do with PHP either. The problem was the NUMERIC value was UNSIGNED in my production environment, meaning VALUES(NUMERICVALUE) was brought from -100 to 0 before it was used.

Answer (score 1):

On my MySQL server (5.7.12), it does work as expected:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE sometable (
       UNIQUEVALUE VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
       NUMERICVALUE INT NOT NULL);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO sometable (UNIQUEVALUE,NUMERICVALUE)
       VALUES ('valuethatexists','100')
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE NUMERICVALUE = NUMERICVALUE+VALUES(NUMERICVALUE);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM sometable;
+-----------------+--------------+
| UNIQUEVALUE     | NUMERICVALUE |
+-----------------+--------------+
| valuethatexists |          100 |
+-----------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO sometable (UNIQUEVALUE,NUMERICVALUE)
       VALUES ('valuethatexists','-100')
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE NUMERICVALUE = NUMERICVALUE+VALUES(NUMERICVALUE);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM sometable;
+-----------------+--------------+
| UNIQUEVALUE     | NUMERICVALUE |
+-----------------+--------------+
| valuethatexists |            0 |
+-----------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which version of MySQL are you using? Can you execute the exact statements above and see if you have different results?

Comment: I just tried SQLFiddel and my own 5.7 DB. You are right - it did as expected. I am doing this through PHP and obviously this goes wrong somewhere else. I will try and investigate further.

Comment: Good, just try to isolate the problem one step at a time :)

Comment: Never mind. I found the problem. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

While Benjamin's answer is correct, the root of the issue turned out to be the fact that the NUMERICVALUE column was UNSIGNED, so whenever I input -100, it was turned into 0 before it was evaluated as VALUES(NUMERICVALUE). If this is to be considered a bug or not I don't know.

Obviously the result of the final evaluation should not be negative, but I don't know how clever it is to silently turn it into 0. I had logic in place making sure the value in question would never be below 0 anyway by never passing a negative value larger than what was already in the row.